# Should a thread-safe object prevent its deletion when other threads might still use it?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'll start by giving a code example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>

class Socket
{

};

class Acceptor
{
public:
    void accept(Socket& socket)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    std::thread thread;

    {
        Socket socket;

        thread = std::thread([&socket]
        {
            Acceptor acceptor;
            acceptor.accept(socket);
        });
    }

    thread.join();

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The classes `Socket` and `Acceptor` are thread-safe. However, should the thread-safety guarantee of `Socket` also prevent the above erroneous code from being written?

The solution would be to allow the thread-safe classes to be created as a `std::shared_ptr` only.

I think it comes down to this that storing references to thread-safe objects should be prevented and using `std::shared_ptr` for that seems suitable. Of course, the library user could just dereference the `std::shared_ptr` and store a reference to that (no prevention for this, right?), but that's already behavior that could be classified as 'intentionally asking for trouble' rather than a programming mistake.